# return false not working in localstoragedb

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm using [localstoragedb](https://github.com/knadh/localStorageDB) for my local database, till now whatever I've done is working correct. But on submitting one of form return false doesn't stop submitting the form.
Here is the code.....

```
$("#registration").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#username').val() === '') {
        $('#username').parent().addClass('error');
        return false;
    };
    if ($('#password').val() === '') {
        $('#password').parent().addClass('error');
        return false;
    };
    if ($('#mobile').val() === '') {
        $('#mobile').parent().addClass('error');
        return false;
    };

    localDb.queryAll("UserInfo");
    localDb.queryAll("UserInfo", {
        query: function(row) {
            if (row.username === $('#username').val()) {
                alert("username already existed");
                return false;
            }

        }

    });


    localDb.insert("UserInfo", {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
        Mobile: $("#mobile").val()
    });
    localDb.commit();
    $(".message").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.replace("login.html");
    }, 2000);

});
```

All the return false work correctly except inside `localDb.queryAll` function.
It will alert me **username already existed** but submitted the form also.
Look like some problem with `return false`.
 Is something i'm missing or doing wrong?????
 Thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 0):

I did a mistake in loop as it continue to search in every row for the particular value and where it wont found it insert it. here is the correct code....

```
$("#registration").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#username').val() === '') {
        $('#username').parent().addClass('error');
        return false;
    };
    if ($('#password').val() === '') {
        $('#password').parent().addClass('error');
        return false;
    };
    if ($('#mobile').val() === '') {
        $('#mobile').parent().addClass('error');
        return false;
    };

    localDb.queryAll("UserInfo");
    localDb.queryAll("UserInfo", {
        query: function(row) {
            if (row.username === $('#username').val()) {
                alert("username already existed");
                return false;
            }

        }

    });


    localDb.insert("UserInfo", {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
        Mobile: $("#mobile").val()
    });
    localDb.commit();
    $(".message").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.replace("login.html");
    }, 2000);

});
```